# Java: Starting loop increment for drawing a multiplication table

Tags: java, for-loop, drawing, increment, multiplication

I am having trouble figuring out how to remove the 0's in this table. I've attempted looking it up online and have had little success figuring it out that way (probably not searching it correctly). I am attempting to get Figure #1 to appear like Figure #2 besides a few stylistic changes.

I'd appreciate any help.

Code: (http://www.buildingjavaprograms.com/DrawingPanel.java) Drawing Panel Used

```
import java.awt.*;

public class IfGridFor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel(400, 520);
        panel.setBackground(Color.blue);
        Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();

        int sizeX = 40;
        int sizeY = 40;
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y <= 12; y++) {               
                int cornerX = x*sizeX;
                int cornerY = y*sizeY;

                if ((x + y) % 2 == 0)
                    g.setColor(Color.green);
                else 
                    g.setColor(Color.yellow);

                g.fillRect(cornerX+1, cornerY+1, sizeX-2, sizeY-2);
                g.setColor(Color.black);
                g.drawString(x  + " * " + y, cornerX + 5, cornerY + 15); // text is
                g.drawString("= " + x * y, cornerX + 5, cornerY + 33); // offsets
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Figure #1:

[image: Figure #1]

Figure #2:

[image: Figure #2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost done - all you need is changing what gets shown from `x`, `y`, `x*y` to `(x+1)`, `(y+1)`, `(x+1)*(y+1)`, and reducing the height of the panel by one row:

```
DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel(400, 480); // 12 rows, not 13
...
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 12; y++) {  // < instead of <=
        ...
        g.drawString((x+1)  + " * " + (y+1), cornerX + 5, cornerY + 15); // text is
        g.drawString("" + (x+1) * (y+1), cornerX + 5, cornerY + 33); // offsets
    }
}
```

The rest of your code (i.e. the `...` parts) remain the same.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to remove the top row and the left column? If so, start your `for` loops at one instead of zero. Also your outer loop should have the condition `x <= 10` if you want the figure to include the square labelled '10'.

Then change the lines:

```
int cornerX = x*sizeX;
int cornerY = y*sizeY;
```

to:

```
int cornerX = (x-1)*sizeX;
int cornerY = (y-1)*sizeY;
```

Comment: I attempted that and it didn't the blue space where they once were, even when adjusting the panel.